# embed window media player in a dialog based application in mfc

Tags: com, mfc, activex

I am trying to embed the embed Window Media Player in a dialog in MFC. I am using these steps:

1. I created one new dialog based application in mfc
2. **Right Click on dialog->Insert ActivexControl->Window Media Player**

Now I want to run a video file at run time. For that I am writing some inside

```
OnInitDialog()
```

I am writing this code inside `OnInitDialog()`

```
BOOL CPlayerDlg::OnInitDialog()
{
    CDialogEx::OnInitDialog();

    // Set the icon for this dialog.  The framework does this automatically
    //  when the application's main window is not a dialog
    SetIcon(m_hIcon, TRUE);         // Set big icon
    SetIcon(m_hIcon, FALSE);        // Set small icon

    // TODO: Add extra initialization here
    HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance(__uuidof(WindowsMediaPlayer), 0, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IOleObject, (void**)&oleObject);

    IWMPPlayer4* pPlayer = NULL;
    hr = oleObject->QueryInterface(__uuidof(IWMPPlayer4), (void**)&pPlayer);
    pPlayer->put_uiMode(_T("full"));

    IWMPSettings *pSettings=NULL;
    hr = pPlayer->QueryInterface(__uuidof(IWMPSettings), (void **)&pSettings);

    IWMPControls *pControls = NULL;
    hr =    pPlayer->QueryInterface(__uuidof(IWMPControls), (void **)&pControls);
    hr =    pPlayer->put_enabled(VARIANT_TRUE);
    hr =    pPlayer->put_URL(_T("abcd.mp3"));   
    hr =    pControls->play();
    hr =    pControls->Release();
    hr =    pPlayer->Release();

    return TRUE;  // return TRUE  unless you set the focus to a control
}
```

here `oleObject` is of type `IOleObject*`

Now I am not able to see the video but I can listen and loose all functionality of window media player like increase or decrease the volume and Play button got disabled. I want to run audio/video files with all functionality of window media player.

I took help from these articles:

```
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd564580(VS.85).aspx
```

Can anyone help me.

Comment: WMP ActiveX control does not have to be a full copy with full feature set of standalone WMP application. You get what you get.

Comment: I didn't understand. Can you elobrate? Or give me other way where I can play the audio / video files at run time.

Comment: I mean that WMP available as ActiveX control has a limited feature set compared to standalone application by design. You can put your own Play button and control player from code. Or you can use other media APIs to play a file as well (DirectShow, Media Foundation - WMP uses them internally for playback).

Comment: but when I give the URL of of an audio/video file by going into property window. I am setting the URL manually.When I do this That time I can pause/play the video, able to stop the video. SO what is the difference between both methods.

Comment: Your `put_URL` with no full path leaving no opportunity to the media player to locate the file in question?

Comment: I am giving relative path of file  to `put_URL` like        `pPlayer->put_URL(_T("C:\\Users\\abc\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2012\\Projects\\Player\\Debug\\abcd.mp4"));`